# no matching function in the async (unresolved type in the template)

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I am having trouble reusing a function called `evaluate`

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
T2 Polynomial<T>::evaluate(T2 val) const {
    int degree = 0;
    return accumulate(coefs.begin(), coefs.end(), T2{0},
                      [&](T2 res, T coef){ return res+coef*pow(val,degree++);} );
}
```

I am trying to call it in a function called `product`

```
template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
    T2 Polynomial<T>::product(T2 val, vector<Polynomial<T>>& polys) {
    vector<future<T2>> futures;
    T2 product = this->evaluate(val);
    // evaluate asynchronously each polynomial with val
    for (Polynomial<T>& p : polys) {
            auto evaluateFunction = [&]() {
            int degree = 0;
            return accumulate(p.coefs.begin(), p.coefs.end(), T2{0},
                              //change [&] to [&val, &degree]
                              [&](T2 res, T coef) { return res + coef * pow(val, degree++); });
        };

        futures.push_back(async(launch::async, this->evaluate(val))); //normally there was a evaluateFunction there
    }

    // compute the final product
    for (auto& fut: futures) {
        product *= fut.get();
    }
    return product;
}
```

Reuse the 'evaluate' function gives an error an error 'no matching function'
in the async (unresolved type in the template) so I had to remake it.

How can I fix this error?
I dont understand what is wrong with `futures.push_back(async(launch::async, this->evaluate(val)));`

Comment: I "think" you are also running into the classic "template function not seen as template at compile time" issue (hard to tell without being able to compile you code). `this->template evaluate(val);` is the funky syntax that fixes that (the issue raised by @Tyker still applies)

Comment: @Frank I get the same error with this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this->evaluate(val)
```

will be evaluated to the result of `this->evaluate(val)` and remplaced

and evaluate should be called on `val` instead of `p`

you should do

```
std::bind(&Polynomial<T>::evaluate, p, val)
```

or with lambda

```
[&]{ return p.evaluate(val); }
```

this will create a callable object from `Polynomial<T>::evaluate` with `p` and `val` as arguments

Comment: You should be prefer lambdas over `std::bind`  unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Frank do u have a solution with lambda?

Comment: @Tyker, using a reference-capture lambda with async is a *bad* idea.

Comment: @Frank i agree but in this case we have vision of the get and values will still be in scope at that point

Comment: ``futures.push_back(async(launch::async, [&]{this->evaluate(val);}));`` still gives ``error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::future<int>, std::allocator<std::future<int> > >::push_back(std::future<void>)'
         futures.push_back(async(launch::async, [&]{this->evaluate(val);}));       ``

Comment: @crystyxn i think we will need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this

Comment: `std::future<int>` - so T2 is int, define `[&]{ return this->evaluate(val);}`

Comment: @rafix07 it did not give an error, but the wrong answer. My test failed.
``REQUIRE( p1.product(5, vec) == 594 )
with expansion:
  1331 (0x533) == 594 (0x252)``

Comment: @Tyker I get the same value back in my test (1331 instead of 594). My test is trying this: 
``Polynomial<int> p1{1, 2};       // p1(x) = 2x + 1
    Polynomial<int> p2{2, 0, 1};    // p2(x) = x^2 + 2
    Polynomial<int> p3{-3, 1};      // p3(x) = x - 3
    // Product: p(x) = (2x+1)*(x^2+2)*(x-3)
    vector<Polynomial<int>> vec{p2, p3};
    REQUIRE(p1.product(5, vec) == 594); // p(5) = 11 * 27 * 2 = 594
    REQUIRE(p1.product(0, vec) == -6); // p(0) = 1 * 2 * -3 = -6``

Comment: Why are you calling `this->evaluate()` in `for (polys)`, maybe it should be `[&]{ return p.evaluate(val); }` call *evaluate* for `p` object.

Comment: @Tyker please edit your answer if anyone needs to see it in the future